# Copying files back to a Specific Folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, filesystems

This program extracts files from a folder that has been modified today, and after the files are placed into another folder a batch file then deletes the rest of the non-modified files in that source folder.

The last thing my program is supposed to do is copy files from separate folder, and place them back into that source folder.

But my program only extracts the modified files, deletes the rest of the files in that folder, but when I run the program to also copy and place the new files into the source folder it just doesn't do it. Does anyone know why?

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmExtractionator

    '  Dim txtFiles1 As Control
    Dim sourceDirectory As String = "F:\CopierFolderforTestDriveCapstone"
    Dim archiveDirectory As String = "F:\FilesExtracted"
    Dim originalDirectory As String = "F:\OriginalTestFiles"

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click

        Try

            Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory)

            If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(archiveDirectory)) Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(archiveDirectory)
            End If


            For Each currentFileLoc As String In txtFiles

                Dim fileName = currentFileLoc.Substring(sourceDirectory.Length + 1)



                If (IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(currentFileLoc).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")) Then
                    MessageBox.Show(currentFileLoc & " moved", "Moved Succesfully")
                    File.Move(currentFileLoc, Path.Combine(archiveDirectory, fileName))

                End If

            Next
        Catch eT As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
        End Try

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("F:\poop.bat")


        Try
            Dim txtFiles2 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(originalDirectory)

            For Each currentFileLoc2 As String In txtFiles2

                Dim fileName = currentFileLoc2.Substring(originalDirectory.Length + 1)

                File.Move(currentFileLoc2, Path.Combine(sourceDirectory, fileName))

            Next
        Catch eT As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(eT.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Dim fileName = currentFileLoc2.Substring(originalDirectory.Length + 1)
```

to

```
Dim FileName = IO.Path.GetFileName(currentFileLoc2)
```

Comment: I changed your answer in my code, but the files from the orginalDirectory were still not copied to the SourceDirectory

Comment: Could it be because the batch file is still deleting the files inside of the source directory while the program is trying to copy the files to the source directory?

Comment: If that other bat file is also working with the files I would consider moving it's logic into .NET code to eliminate it from the possible issues causing the problem. Having 2 different processes manipulating files adds a complexity level similar to multiple threads and I don't think that is really needed.

Comment: OR change your dealing with the batch file to force .NET to wait for it to complete it's work.
Eg.
Dim p As Process = Process.Start("F:\poop.bat")
p.WaitForExit()